# After deleting partition, I cannot boot from usb

Tags: linux, usb, installation, grub, bootloader

I have installed linux mint alongside windows on my laptop. At that point I had windows-10 and linux mint, but the only way to load linux was to boot from usb!
I decided to reinstall linux again and to do that I deleted the linux partitions.

When I boot from hdd everything is ok (windows is loaded), but when I boot from usb I always have grub rescue menu prompt.

> error: no such device: 662xxxx-yyyy-tttt-1111... 
>   enter the rescue mode... 
>   grub rescue>_

What should I do to boot linux from usb? What did I do?

Comment: Just to be clear, you plan to install Linux on the laptop via a USB drive?

Comment: Yes. I already did, but I reverted because the way I installed (alongside windows 10) didn't let me see the grub.

Comment: That will happen if you install Linux first as Windows has a habit of overwriting other OS's boot settings. Now that you have WIndows already installed, I suggest creating the USB again if necessary and booting from it to reinstall Linux. This time, you should have any issues with the boot settings being overwritten by Windows which is already installed.

Comment: Actually I Installed Linux in a second time (the laptop is a windows one).  I think I overwrote the mbr of the usb during the linux installation.

Comment: That's only possible if you chose to install Linux in the USB itself instead of on the drive of the laptop. Try again and be sure that you are installing on the laptop drive and not the USB.